# Selenium compare stored Text with NOT or != operator

Tags: selenium, operators, compare

i'm trying to compare the content of two variables in order to return if variable1 != variable2.
I found some different examples, how to compare variables, but not how to use this with an operator.

First of all, i store text, wait 5 minutes and store text again. If the text is different, so the testis passed.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>id=newsdiv_1</td>
    <td>newsBox1</td>
</tr>
<!--wait 6 min for ajax update-->
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>360000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>id=newsdiv_1</td>
    <td>newsBox2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyExpression</td>
    <td>${newsBox1}</td>
    <td>regexp=!(${newsBox2})</td>
</tr>
```

`verifyExpression`works perfect in comparing if 2 variables are equal. 
But the last test should work like this: `if newsBox1!=newsBox2 than return true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `verifyNotExpression`, which is basically a not of the `verifyExpression`:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyNotExpression</td>
    <td>${newsBox1}</td>
    <td>${newsBox2}</td>
</tr>
```